# Prove the set of contiguous interval of Cantor set is countable.

Tags: cantor-set

Prove the set of contiguous interval of Cantor set is countable.

Remember that means one of the "holes" you cut out when constructing the Cantor set and we know that Cantor set is uncountable but I want to know about these "holes". So every contiguous interval contains a rational. And Rational Numbers are countable then the set of contiguous interval is countable. Am I right?.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Correct. More generally, any family of pairwise disjoint non-empty open intervals in $\Bbb R$ must be countable for the same reason.

Comment: if you want to explain it strictly with mathematical language, how could I do it?

Comment: What you said in the question is already pretty clear. You could be a little more precise, something like this: Each of the open intervals removed in the construction of the middle-thirds Cantor set must contain a rational number, and these intervals are pairwise disjoint, so each must contain a different rational number. There are only countably many rational numbers, so there can be only countably many of these intervals.

Comment: If you're not dealing with an arbitrary Cantor set (nonempty perfect nowhere dense compact subset of the reals), but one in which you specifically know is constructed in stages (middle thirds, middle tenths, non-uniform type, etc.), then you might think that countability is immediate from the construction --- there are finitely many contiguous intervals at each of the countably many construction stages. But it seems to me that we still need to close off the possibility that many additional (perhaps uncountably many) contiguous intervals appear when those infinitely many intervals are removed.